# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute '_get_axis_number'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the percentage change in value of today compared to yesterday, for every day in the dataframe. This is the line that throws the error-

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'new_cases':[368060.0,
 357316.0,
 382146.0,
 412431.0,
 414188.0,
 401078.0,
 403405.0,
 366494.0,
 329942.0]})

df['percent_increase_cases'] = df['new_cases'].apply(pd.Series.pct_change)
```

The formula I am using is

> percent_increase = (today's cases - yesterday's cases) / yesterday's
> cases * 100

It works if I use the code below but I wanted to make it cleaner.

```
df['percent_increase_cases'] = (df['new_cases'].diff(1)) / df['new_cases'].shift(1) * 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what is happening is that `apply()` applies the function `pd.Series.pct_change` to each *element* of the series `df['new_cases']`, rather than to the series as a whole. For example, if I run

```py
pd.Series.pct_change(df['new_cases'])
```

then I get this:

```
0         NaN
1   -0.029191
2    0.069490
3    0.079250
4    0.004260
5   -0.031652
6    0.005802
7   -0.091499
8   -0.099734
Name: new_cases, dtype: float64
```

However, if I apply `pd.Series.pct_change` to the first element of `df['new_cases']`, 368060.0, like this,

```py
pd.Series.pct_change(368060.0)
```

then I reproduce your error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-7aee3ee9524c>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.Series.pct_change(368060.0)

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 10078, in pct_change
    axis = self._get_axis_number(kwargs.pop("axis", self._stat_axis_name))

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute '_get_axis_number'
```

Looks like the solution, then, is to run either

```py
pd.Series.pct_change(df['new_cases'])*100
```

or equivalently,

```py
df['new_cases'].pct_change()*100
```

The factor of 100 is there so you get a percent rather than a decimal fraction, consistent with your original formula, `(df['new_cases'].diff(1)) / df['new_cases'].shift(1) * 100`.

Comment: I can actually swap the series itself for `pd.Series`! That makes perfect sense! And looks so elegant. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another, simpler method of doing this would be

```
df['percent_increase_cases'] = df[['new_cases']].apply(pd.Series.pct_change)
```

Notice the extra pair of `[]` when selecting columns.

Selecting a single column from a dataframe returns a series, which would run in to the problems described by [@jjramsey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67504452/913098), but selecting a list of columns keeps the dataframe as a dataframe, not running into trouble.